# How to override BootStrap CSS checkboxs and input checkboxs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a problem over-riding the bootstrap css for checkboxes and input checkboxes. I have a checkboxlist and the bootstraps styling is over-riding my own css file. I have doubled checked and made sure that it wasn't bootstraps themes causing the issue but it is the bootstraps css.

I have also tried using `!important`
in my css and it still gets over-ridden, I even placed my css file after the bootstraps css, tried putting my css before it, even tried

```
input[type=checkbox]
```

and that did nothing as well.

Here is the css I'm trying to use to override the bootstrap

```
.CheckBoxSubjects td {
border-style: solid;
border: 1px solid #78E389;
width: 122px;
height: 27px;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color:#78E389;
}
```

Comment: give me css declation code, and Try to using inline CSS

Answer (score 2):

Here's the fiddle of the code I used. Hope this helps for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/cLaty/

HTML

```
<div class="checkbox pull-right">
      <input type="checkbox" id="remember" /><label for="remember">Remember me</label>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
position: absolute;
left: -9999px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
position: relative;
padding-left: 25px;
cursor: pointer;
}

 /* checkbox aspect */
 input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:before,
 input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 left:0; top: 2px;
 width: 17px; height: 17px;
 border: 1px solid #aaa;
 background: #f8f8f8;
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3)
 }
 /* checked mark aspect */
 input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after,
 input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
content: '✔';
position: absolute;
top: 0; left: 4px;
font-size: 14px;
color: #4cc0c1;
transition: all .2s;
-webkit-transition: all .2s;
-moz-transition: all .2s;
-ms-transition: all .2s;
-o-transition: all .2s;
}
/* checked mark aspect changes */
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
opacity: 0;
transform: scale(0);
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
opacity: 1;
transform: scale(1);
}
/* disabled checkbox */
input[type="checkbox"]:disabled:not(:checked) + label:before,
input[type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label:before {
box-shadow: none;
border-color: #999999;
background-color: #ddd;
} 
input[type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label:after {
color: #999;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label {
color: #aaa;
}
 /* accessibility */
 input[type="checkbox"]:checked:focus + label:before,
 input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked):focus + label:before {
 border: inherit;
}
```

Comment: That's what I'm trying to get rid of, the bootstrap is making my checkboxlist checkboxes to close together, no separation. When I use the css without bootstrap, the checkboxes are nicely separated. Bootstrap is making them muddled.

Comment: This how I am using it. Things are fine for me this way. "<div class="form-group">
          <a class="pull-right" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
          <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword">
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox pull-right">
          <input type="checkbox" id="remember" /><label for="remember">Remember me</label>
        </div>"